# The archive is either in unknown format or damaged Error when download file in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, zip

When i download the specified directory in Zip format, file is download successfully. But when extract the appropriate zip it shows the"The archive is either in unknown format or damaged" error.

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', 'on');
    $foldername = $_REQUEST['file'];
    // Enter the name of directory
    $pathdir = "edit/uploads/".$foldername; 
    echo "Path : $pathdir";
    $dir = $pathdir; //folder path
    $archive = "$foldername.zip";
    $zip = new ZipArchive;
    $zip->open($archive, ZipArchive::CREATE);
    $files = scandir($dir);
    //print_r($files);exit;
    unset($files[0], $files[1]);
    foreach ($files as $file) {
    $zip->addFile($file);
    }
    $zip->close();
    header('Content-Type: application/zip');
    header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename='.$archive);
    header('Content-Length: '.filesize($archive));
    ob_end_clean();
    readfile($archive);
    unlink($archive);
    ?>
```

Program Error:-

**Warning**:  readfile(5550002.zip): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in **/home/njogw/public_html/demo/webapp/cad/download_zip.php** on line **27**

**Warning**:  unlink(5550002.zip): No such file or directory in **/home/njogw/public_html/demo/webapp/cad/download_zip.php** on line **28**

Comment: Side note: You should sanitize `$foldername` to prevent directory traversal vulnerabilities.

Comment: Immediately after the `unlink` line, try putting `exit`

Comment: @mario I see that zip file for the following program error :-<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  readfile(5550002.zip): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in <b>/home/njogw/public_html/demo/webapp/cad/download_zip.php</b> on line <b>27</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  unlink(5550002.zip): No such file or directory in <b>/home/njogw/public_html/demo/webapp/cad/download_zip.php</b> on line <b>28</b><br />

Comment: Well, then that's your question. Now do some thought process on the file names and paths as mentioned by the warning. Remember that noone else can deduce and see *your* directory structure.

Comment: Could you tell us what happens if you 'die' your process after $zip->open? Does 5550002.zip exist? If not could you check PHP's rights on your system and if it has write right?